# Check if contour inside another contour

Tags: python, opencv

I have one contour(sectionScreen) and list of contours(validCircles).I need a function returning contours from validCircles that are inside contour screens
I'm currently using something like this:

```
def groupCircles(validCircles,lineIntervals,sectionScreen):
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(sectionScreen)
    circlesInside = []
    for i in validCircles:
        x0,y0,_,_ = cv2.boundingRect(i)
        if x<x0<x+w and y<y0<y+h:
            circlesInside.append(i)
return circlesInside
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: Please show your code for finding the contours.  Also it would be helpful to see and image of your contours. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0  and https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html for contour hierarchy

Comment: @Hikmet Guleliyev. You' drawn boundingRect not but circles.

Comment: Using bounding rect is cheap and fast, but only an approximate. Simple but probably not the fastest way is to draw each of the contours filled to separate images/masks A and B and then check cv2.countNonZero(AB) == cv,2.countNonZero(B) to test whether B is fully included in A. cv2.countNonZero(AB) == 0 when there is no intersection at all.